# How to eliminate this variable from set of simultaneous quadratic forms, in terms of determinants?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, quadratics, matrix-equations, quadratic-forms

I am working through some of the derivations [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0202090)

In the appendix (p23, Eq. B.17), we arrive at a set of quadratic equations for variables $E,L$ of the form:

$$f_1 E^2 - 2g_1 E L - h_1 L^2 - d_1 = 0$$

$$f_2 E^2 - 2g_2 E L - h_2 L^2 - d_2 = 0$$

where the $f_i,g_i,h_i,d_i$ can just be viewed as constants for this discussion

The author then eliminates $L$ to obtain a quadratic in $E^2$ as,

$$ (\rho + 4 \eta \sigma) E^4 - 2(\kappa \rho + 2 \epsilon \sigma) E^2 + \kappa^2 \tag{1}\label{1}$$

where $\epsilon, \eta, \kappa, \rho, \sigma$ are defined as determinants of matrices which are functions of the $f_i,g_i,h_i,d_i$ e.g.

$$ \kappa = \begin{vmatrix}
d_1 & h_1 \\
d_2 & h_2
\end{vmatrix} $$

with the other parameters defined in the paper as Eqs B.19 - B.21.

**My question is** how does the author take this step and eliminate $L$ and arrive at Eq. 1? Is there a way to formulate this as some matrix problem? I fail to see where the determinants have come from!

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the first equation by $h_2$ and the second equation by $h_1$ and subtract gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
(f_1h_2-f_2h_1)E^2-2(g_1h_2-g_2h_1)EL-(d_1h_2-d_2h_1)=0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Similarly multiply the first equation by $g_2$ and the second equation by $g_1$ and subtract gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
(f_1g_2-f_2g_1)E^2-(h_1g_2-h_2g_1)L^2-(d_1g_2-d_2g_1)=0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now rearrange the first equation (in this answer) to 
\begin{eqnarray*}
2(g_1h_2-g_2h_1)EL =(f_1h_2-f_2h_1)E^2-(d_1h_2-d_2h_1)
\end{eqnarray*}
and square this and eliminate $L^2$ by rearrange the second eqaution to $(h_1g_2-h_2g_1)L^2=?$.

This will give a quadratic in $E^2$ as required.